# sequence with and without recursion

Tags: c, recursion, recurrence

I have a sequence.

```
a1 = 1 - cos(x);
ai = a1 + (-1)^(i-1) * x^(2*i-2) / (2*i-2)!
```

I need to write this with and without recursion. But it has a different results.
Here is my code: http://codepaste.net/q213q6

Comment: looks like homework. please put this tag if true

Comment: I guess your sequence is meant to converge to zero. If so, it should be defined as a_i = a_(i-1) + ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to operate under the assumption that this is homework, if I'm wrong I'll come back and edit this post or repost.

Firstly, you should try to write your factorial function in a tail recursive manner. Though it probably won't make much difference in C, it's good practice.

```
int helper( int x, int acc ) {
    if( x == 0 ) {
        return acc;
    }
    else {
      return helper( x - 1, acc * x );
    }
}

int factorial( x ) {
  helper( x, 1 );
}
```

Next, you don't generally want to put a loop inside of your recursive functions, that somewhat defeats the point. Think of a recursive call as one iteration with a test and either return or recall.

Comment: Do you mean `helper (x - 1, acc * x)`? `factorial`, the way you defined it, only takes one argument.

Comment: I did, thank you. I decided to make the helper a helper instead of the actual function half way through and forgot to finish fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing floating point arithmetic. Different ways of implementation can produce different results.
In your case i can think of one place where losses are incurred

```
currC = pow(x, 2*i-2);
```

is not equal to

```
  47:          currC = currC * x * x;
```

For more information,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Multiplication